# Why do I get a runtime exception while trying to load fxml file in my program

Tags: java, exception, javafx

I am learning javafx and now I am trying to apply the techniques I learnt in my java applications. My program is called "WhatsTheTime" which is a simple program which consists of an AnchorPane with an Image of a clock in it. When the pane is clicked, it is supposed to set the text of the label behind the ImageView with the current time and the clock image is set to be invisible. When I try to run the application, I get a runtimeException in the `loader.load()` statement. While searching on the internet, I found that it is mostly due to incorrectly specifying the fileName, but I checked the fileName and it is absolutely correct.

This is my fxml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.shape.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>

<fx:root type = "AnchorPane" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" 
  minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" onMouseClicked="#getTheTime"  prefHeight="198.0" prefWidth="208.0" type="AnchorPane"  
  xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="myPrototypes.WhatsTheTime">
  <children>
  <Rectangle arcHeight="5.0" arcWidth="5.0" height="200.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" width="208.0" />
  <Label fx:id="timeLabel" layoutX="90.0" layoutY="90.0" text="Label" />
  <ImageView fx:id="clockImage" fitHeight="186.0" fitWidth="193.0" layoutX="7.0" layoutY="7.0">
     <image>
        <Image url="@../../What'sTheTimeIcon.png" />
     </image>
  </ImageView>
  </children>
  </fx:root>
```

This is my Controller class:

```
package myPrototypes;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;

public class WhatsTheTime extends AnchorPane{

@FXML
private ImageView clockImage;

@FXML
private Label timeLabel;

WhatsTheTime(){
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader
            (getClass().getResource("WhatsTheTime.fxml"));

    loader.setRoot(this);
    loader.setController(this);

    try{
        loader.load();
    }
    catch(IOException e){
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
}

@FXML
public void getTheTime(){
    clockImage.setVisible(false);

    SimpleDateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
    Date date = new Date();

    timeLabel.setText(timeFormat.format(date));
}
}
```

And this is my main class:

```
package myPrototypes;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class WhatsTheTimeMain extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    WhatsTheTime component = new WhatsTheTime();

    Scene scene = new Scene(component);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.sizeToScene();
    primaryStage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```

Please help me solve this problem. Tell me if you need any other information

Comment: Please post the exception stack trace - you can get it in the console by adding `e.printStackTrace()` inside your `catch` block.

Comment: Using the `type` attribute twice in the samle element may not be the best idea...

Comment: @fabian, your idea has also worked together with the answer below. Thank you very much for your contribution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you specify a controller class in the FXML via the `fx:controller` attribute, you are instructing the `FXMLLoader` to instantiate that class during the `load()` process, and use the instance as the controller object.

However, in your case you are explicitly setting a controller on the loader prior to invoking load:

```
loader.setController(this);
```

Since the controller is already set when the FXML is loaded, this generates an exception. (If you read the stack trace, you will see it includes an error message along the lines of "Controller already specified".)

Remove the `fx:controller` attribute from the root element of the FXML:

```xml
<fx:root type = "AnchorPane" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" 
  minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" onMouseClicked="#getTheTime"  prefHeight="198.0" prefWidth="208.0"  
  xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" >
```

(Note: there may be other errors: this is the one that is immediately obvious. You should include the stack trace in your question for more complete answers.)

Comment: Thanks for your idea very much, now I am able to correct my mistake and my program displays the time correctly when I click on the pane. Also, through your advice I will be able to save hours not repeating the mistake I have done right now. Thank you!